# C++ adding n strings to a string stream

Tags: c++

I am kind of stuck in pre C++ 11 land. How can I write a function that takes n strings and appends them to an ostreamstream?

```
void Foo(std::string first_part, ...){
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << first_part << ...; // cant do it
    for(int i = 0; i < ....length(); i++){ // :|
    }
}
```

If I lived in a perfect world I could do the above. Is there any other way pre C++ 11 to loop through the `...` arguments?

Comment: Why are you using variadic arguments?

Comment: Do you have an upper limit on how many parameters you'll accept?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Why not? ..

Comment: @NathanOliver No, not really.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic

Comment: Because there are better ways do to what you want (i.e `std::vector`).

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing C++11 variadic templates (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) with pure C variadic functions (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) ? These may look similar, but are totally different.

Comment: Also, I remember there being a clause in the C++ standard that variadic functions are not safe for types that are not POD types.  Need to go find it...

Comment: You said you have no upper limit for parameter count, but are you sure? Is 50 enough? 100? Generating 50-100 thin wrapper functions seems like a plausible solution (if you really have to). You could even use Boost.Preprocessor for that, removing the need for external tools.

Comment: If you break this down, youi'll be fine:
`int cppmain(const std::string& program, const std::vector<std::string>& args) {
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return cppmain(argv[0], {argv+1, argv+argc});
}
`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it can't be done directly (at least not in portable code).

Attempting to pass a non-trivial type (including std::string) as a variadic argument gives undefined behavior.

If you want to do something similar, you could (for one example) pass the *addresses* of a number of strings rather than attempting to pass the strings themselves.

If you do that, you'll still have to contend with one other detail: you'll need to tell the receiving function the number of (addresses of) strings to expect.

From there, the receiving function would use `va_start`, `va_arg` and `va_end` to retrieve the data and do it's thing with them.